# Unity 8 black screen

Tags: unity, unity8

I had downloaded Unity 8 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and after I log into it, only a black screen shows up, when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, some sort of command line opens, and there I type my username and pass and then type `startx`, then only my desktop wallpaper can be seen, without any status bar, and the cursor is a cross-hair, a can use terminal, I can make folders and open them but there is nothing except those windows, no launcher and no status bar.

Please help! I installed Ubuntu for unity 8!

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to revert to unity-7 do:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

As of now, unity-8 is riddled with bugs, and doesn't work with a lot of graphics drivers. (It only works with open-source graphics drivers)

In case you want to test it on your system, you could follow this guide: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-test-mir-and-unity-8-on-ubuntu-16-04/